# Hamburger Menu Not Opened

Tags: html, css

I am converting my desktop menu in the mobile menu, but the code is not working.

I am using checkbox trick, when checkbox is checked the menu will appear, otherwise menu display will be none.

At `1280px` my desktop will switched into mobile, but it's not working properly as expected.

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Soofyantheband</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style2.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/mini-nav_bar.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Webpage Wrap inside "wrapper" -->
    <div id="wrapper">
    <!--1.Header Section-->
        <div class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="nav">       
                    <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
                    <header>
                        <div id="band_Logo">
                            <a href="#wrapper"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu" class="menu" style="line-height:94px; ">
                            <ul style="margin:0">           
                                <li><a href="#wrapper" style="color:#ffab00; margin-top: 2px;">Home</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="#section3" style="margin-top: 2px; color:#ffab00;">Events</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="#projectDesc" style="margin-top: 2px; color:#ffab00;">Projects</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="soofyan-unplugged.html" style="margin-top: 2px; color:#ffab00;">Unplugged</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="../Parallax/gallery.html" style="margin-top: 2px; color:#ffab00;">Gallery</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="../Parallax/videos.html" style="margin-top: 2px; color:#ffab00;">Videos</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="../Parallax/about.html" style="margin-top: 2px; color:#ffab00;">About</a></li>
                                <li ><a href="../Parallax/contact.html" style="margin-top: 2px; color:#ffab00;">Contact Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

html {
    font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
}

.nav {
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;*/
    text-align: right;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
}

.menu {
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.menu ul li  {
    clear: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
    margin: 0 10px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display:none;
}

span {
    color: #54D17A;
}  

label {
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: none;
    width: 26px;
    float: right;
}

#toggle {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    label {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .menu ul {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
    .menu ul li a{
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #toggle:checked + .menu ul li a{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: `input` elements are self-closing void tags and cannot contain nested elements. Consider removing the `header` from `input`, then to apply styles to the `header` element when the checkbox is checked, follow this approach: `input[type=checkbox]:checked + header`. Want learn more? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/

Comment: Did you realised that you have 2 `href` properties here: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css"/>`? Try to fix that to see if helps.

Answer (score 1):

There were some issues in your code.

1. This line `#toggle:checked + .menu ul li a` won't work. `.menu` is not a sibling of `#toggle`, it is a child of a sibling (`header`). Instead, use the general sibling combinator (`~`) to target the header.
2. You set `display: none` for the `ul` and `li`, but then only changed the `display` type for the `ul`. Setting `display: none` for the `ul` is sufficient.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
}

.nav {
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;*/
  text-align: right;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

.menu ul li {
  clear: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  margin: 0 10px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

span {
  color: #54D17A;
}

label {
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: none;
  width: 26px;
  float: right;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
  label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .menu ul {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  .menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #toggle:checked ~ header .menu ul {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <!--1.Header Section-->
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav">

        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <header>

          <div id="band_Logo">
            <a href="#wrapper"></a>
          </div>

          <div id="menu" class="menu" style="line-height:94px; ">

            <ul style="margin:0">

              <li><a href="#wrapper" style="color:#ffab00; margin-top: 2px;">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section3" style="margin-top: 2px; color:#ffab00;">Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="#projectDesc" style="margin-top: 2px; color:#ffab00;">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="soofyan-unplugged.html" style="margin-top: 2px; color:#ffab00;">Unplugged</a></li>
              <li><a href="../Parallax/gallery.html" style="margin-top: 2px; color:#ffab00;">Gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="../Parallax/videos.html" style="margin-top: 2px; color:#ffab00;">Videos</a></li>
              <li><a href="../Parallax/about.html" style="margin-top: 2px; color:#ffab00;">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="../Parallax/contact.html" style="margin-top: 2px; color:#ffab00;">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine but whole ul show as inline-block horizontally, no vertical ul

Comment: @Zia How do you want the menu to appear?

Comment: i want vertically displayed menu for mobile devices after 1280px

Comment: Your solution working fine, jut i need to display vertically

Comment: The answer I posted shows the menu displayed vertically. Do you mean, above 1280px you want it to be shown horizontally?

Comment: below 1280px i want to displayed as vertically, above 1280px it will displayed as it is inline-block......but after 1280px it should be displayed as block, but i didn't get expected result